# Issues with custom layout for spinner for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-controls, spinner

I know there is a lot of discussions around custom spinners, however I am still not able to grasp how to do it. What I want is a spinner with a custom layout for the dropdown items and a custom layout for the spinner when not "activated". When the app runs the spinner have the specific layout(when not activated) however when activated it chrashes, which makes me believe there might be a problem with the xml. But here it goes(btw I use mono and c#);

I create a ArrayAdapter for the spinner this way, where I set a layout for the spinner Resource.Layout.SpinnerView and for the dropdown Resource.Layout.SpinnerRow:

```
ArrayAdapter  spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.Context,Resource.Layout.SpinnerView,Resource.Id.spinnertext,_listOfUmbracoItems);       
spinnerArrayAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Resource.Layout.SpinnerRow);
```

Resource.Layout.SpinnerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/dk.appsfabrikken.cmsapp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
  <ImageView
      android:src="@drawable/eduvalg"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:scaleType="centerInside"
       android:padding="0.0dp"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:id="@+id/backgroundimageview" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/spinnertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Resource.Layout.SpinnerRow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/down"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And I add the spinner to the activity layout with the following xml:

```
<CmsApp.Droid.Controls.UmbracoSpinner
      android:id="@+id/spinnerMenu"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
      />
```

I tried to use the the samelayout Resource.Layout.SpinnerView for both and then the app would not chrash - however then i have not the correct custom layout for the drop down items.

I hope someone can help me and point me in the right direction.

---UPDATE---
The following is log when i chrashes and it seems to be an nullpointer which I dont fully understand.

```
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:353)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:376)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:329)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:325)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at com.android.internal.widget.WeightedLinearLayout.onMeasure(WeightedLinearLayout.java:60)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-26 22:45:47.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys I solved it myself and it might be a newbie mistake I am not sure. I needed to make changes to my layout xml files. The id for the textview needs to be the same or else it results in a null pointer exception.

I have changed my xml to the following

Resource.Layout.SpinnerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/dk.appsfabrikken.cmsapp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
  <ImageView
      android:src="@drawable/eduvalg"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:scaleType="centerInside"
       android:padding="0.0dp"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:id="@+id/backgroundimageview" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/spinnertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Resource.Layout.SpinnerRow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/spinnertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/down"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in your Resource.Layout.SpinnerRow the textview have to be checkedtextview

Comment: I just gave it a try and it did not result in anything different. The app still chrashed when I activate the spinner. But thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: can you give us some log when the app crashes ?